# Anyway to Upsert database using PostgreSQL in Python

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, upsert

I want to upsert with least effort, for simplicity, i reduce columns, this not work:

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO temp.tickets
    (id, created_at, updated_at, emails, status)
VALUES
    (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    ON CONFLICT (id)
    DO UPDATE SET ( emails, status) values (%s,%s) 
    
    '''

cursor = cm.cursor()
## cm is a custom module
cursor.execute(sql, (ticket['id'],
                     ticket['created_at'],
                     ticket['updated_at'],
                     ticket['emails'], ticket['status'], )
```

This code show Error:

```
    return super(DictCursor, self).execute(query, vars)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What I need to change in the `cursor.execute()` to work?

The Bellow code work but I like to use `%s` instead of type: `email = excluded.email` for each columns

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO temp.tickets
    (id, created_at, updated_at, emails, status)
VALUES
    (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    ON CONFLICT (id)
    DO UPDATE SET emails = excluded.eamils, status = excluded.status
    
    '''

cursor = cm.cursor() 
# cm is a custom module

cursor.execute(sql, (ticket['id'],
                     ticket['created_at'],
                     ticket['updated_at'],
                     ticket['emails'], ticket['status'], )
```

There are two Relevant Questions [link1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167591/postgresql-psycopg2-upsert-syntax-to-update-columns/167598#167598?newreg=ebb0072f838d41f58179900020711c33), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55922003/update-multiple-columns-on-conflict-postgres)

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO temp.tickets
    (id, created_at, updated_at, emails, status)
VALUES
    (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    ON CONFLICT (id)
    DO UPDATE SET ( emails, status) values (%s,%s) 
    
    '''

cursor = cm.cursor()
## cm is a custom module
cursor.execute(sql, (ticket['id'],
                     ticket['created_at'],
                     ticket['updated_at'],
                     ticket['emails'], 
                     ticket['status'],
                     ticket['emails'], 
                      ticket['status'] )
```

Thre number of `%s` must match the number of parameters.

Comment: when I change the `cursor.execute()` it show: `Error: psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "values" LINE 6:         DO UPDATE SET ( emails, status) values (ARRAY['su...`

Answer (score -1):

When Postgres encounters a captured conflict it basically creates a record called EXCLUDED that contains the values you attempted to insert, You can refer to this record in DO UPDATE.  Try the following:

```
INSERT INTO temp.tickets
    (id, created_at, updated_at, emails, status)
VALUES
    (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    ON CONFLICT (id)
    DO UPDATE 
          SET emails = excluded.emails
            , status = excluded.status
            , updated_at = excluded.updated_at    -- my assumption.  
 ...
```

You will have to format is into the requirements of your source language.

Comment: So this means I need to type for each columns?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "type each column". You have coded %s which I presume each one is a parameter to your insert. This should not change how you pass them in your original statement.   If you mean that you must assign a data type again that would be a feature of your source language.  The *only thing different* from your original  is the code after DO UPDATE.

Comment: Your answer is same as the second code block of mine that works, I mean any other way not to type like this `emails = excluded.emails` for each parameter, but use `%s` instead and change the python code below.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Postgres in totally unaware of the meaning of ant of the particular place holder (%s). It knows only the position, if you use the same variable from your source more than once you need a place holder for each occurrence.   That is what @Renato has suggested. You may be able to a numeric notation, so for email is  %4s and status is %5s for status, and repeat the same in the DO Update, but I do not know if Postgres supports that. I never tried it just to avoid typing.

Comment: So do you have new solution? could you type it? @belayer

Comment: No I cannot, I gave you a couple ideas you can try and or research. I do not know Python, at least to extent needed. For me I would just type column=excluded.column as needed. By now I would be done.